# How is the Web Version of the Report Viewer Rendered?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm curious about how the ReportViewer is rendered. I have noticed that within the MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER > Reporting Services > Report Server > Pages folder there is an aspx page called ReportViewer. I thought that might be the page that is rendering the ReportViewer. Is there an ability to modify this page in order to have more control over how the ReportViewer is rendered? Along the same path, I also see a Styles folder with the files HtmlViewer, SP_Full and SP_Small. Are these files used to render the ReportViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alot of questions you are asking here.

Indeed the reportserver uses the Reportviewer to render the reports, more information on this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251771(VS.90).aspx

On the reportserver there are several configuration files which alter the rendering, configuration, security etc.. see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866.aspx

As for the stylesheets: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx

I hope this helps!